# How to make a 'text box' responsive to different lengths of texts

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As you can see in the snippet below, I have some text in the `<p>` element, now let's say the `<p>` text changes (in the front-end) to something different like 'The night is dark, cold, chilly' for example with different width, how can I get the box to be responsive? So keeping the same padding all around the text? I've right now placed it there using `margin-left: 55%;`

```css
.full {
width: 500px;
height: 400px;
background-color: grey;
}

p {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 55%; /* THIS HAS TO edited out? */
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="full">
  <p>The woods are green</p>

</div>
```

Comment: margin:auto perhaps?

Comment: float:right, the easiest one

Comment: `display: table;` and `margin-left: auto;` in `p`

Comment: @s.kuznetsov Thank you! I did that and then the table was centered, addded margin-right: 0; and now it stays to the right bottom and it keeps the padding when different text is inside. Thank you :)

Comment: @Panic, no problem.